# What does the static InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress() return?

Tags: java, network-programming, java-7

Java 7 adds a new static method to the class `java.net.InetAddress`:

```
static InetAddress getLoopbackAddress()
Returns the loopback address.
```

Now I wonder what address will be contained in the result, the IP4 or the IP6 one.

The [documentation](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLoopbackAddress()) is a bit foggy on the subject:

> The InetAddress returned will represent the IPv4 loopback address, 127.0.0.1, or the IPv6 loopback address, ::1. The IPv4 loopback address returned is only one of many in the form 127.*.*.*

How does Java decide whether to return `127.0.0.1` or the IPv6 pendant `::1`?

Or are they both represented by the same InetAdress object?

Is the result always the same? Does it depend on my network card(s)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the other answers given here are wrong.

Java, by default, *prefers IPv6 stack* (if available) but *prefers IPv4 addresses*. Note the subtle difference. This is controlled by `java.net.preferIPv4Stack` and `java.net.preferIPv6Addresses` system properties, both of which default to false.

Hence, the `InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress()` will almost always return an IPv4 address. You would have to set `java.net.preferIPv6Addresses` system properties to `true` in order to get it to return an IPv6 address.

I don't see any OS dependency for the outcome of this method in the JDK sources. I can't think of an OS where Java would not (with default settings) return an IPv4 address for this method.

Comment: Are you sure that _preferIPv6Addresses = false_ automatically implies that it prefers IPv4 addresses? It could simply mean it doesn't have any special preference.

Comment: @atticae. Went through the JDK sources plus did a test myself. So, yes, I'm sure. I can only speak for how `java.net.preferIPv6Addresses` applies to the outcome of the `InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress()` method as it is only for this method I've dug into the source code.

Answer (score 4):

First, there is a fundamental difference between `.getLocalHost()` and this method: `.getLocalHost()` will get the address registered with the *machine name*, whereas `.getLoopbackAddress()` will return the local-only, loopback address.

As to the returned address, it is OS dependent. However, you can influence the JVM to use IPv4 in priority by passing `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to the JVM arguments, or by using:

```
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have an IPv6 stack and Java isn't configured to prefer IPv4, it will return ::1.

Otherwise it will return 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Not sure this is correct. At least in Java 7 the default setting is to prefer IPv6 **stack** but to prefer IPv4 **addresses** (note the difference). This means that `InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress()` will return an IPv4 address by default on most modern OS'es. There are [two different properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/ipv6_guide/#ipv6-networking) to control this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure EJP is entirely correct, he just left out the implied " addresses" after "IPv4" in his answer. If an IPv6 stack is present (which is a property that, if you read your link, is *removed* when you set the preferred stack to be IPv4), but IPv4 addresses are not preferred, then IPv6 addresses will be defaulted to.